# Is it possible to that primary column value independent in each schema partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My table structure is below:

```
CREATE TABLE [ACC].[Document](
    [DocumentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentTypeID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentID] ASC
)
```

I want to partitioning my table on `SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID` column. is it possible to DocumentID column value reset on each partition. in other word DocumentID in each partition wat independent by DocumentID in other partition.

Comment: No, not if it's going to remain as `IDENTITY()`. Why would you want it to?

Comment: accounting men archive their document separately  for each financial period. and want to have reference number for each financial period started from 1.

Comment: what is the best practices for have independent number on each partitaion of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact criteria you could create a view if the reference numbers are only needed on the fly:

```
CREATE VIEW Acc.PartitionedDocument
AS
    SELECT  DocumentID,
            Date,
            SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod,
            DocumentTypeID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod ORDER BY DocumentID) [PartitionDocumentID]
    FROM    Acc.Document
```

However, this will change if documents are deleted. Otherwise your only alternative as far as I am aware with SQL-Server 2008 is to maintain a sequence either with a trigger or within your application layer. Below is how I would achieve this with a trigger.

```
-- ADD ADDITIONAL COLUMN
ALTER TABLE Acc.Document ADD ParitionDocumentID INT NULL
GO
-- UPDATE EXISTING ROWS
;WITH Doc AS
(   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod ORDER BY DocumentID) [RowNumber]
    FROM    Acc.Document
)
UPDATE  Doc
SET     PartitionDocumentID = RowNumber

GO
-- ADD CONSTRAINT TO ENSURE NO DUPLICATES
ALTER TABLE Acc.Document ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Acc_Document UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (PartitionDocumentID, SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID)
GO
-- ADD TRIGGER TO MAINTAIN NEW COLUMN
CREATE TRIGGER acc.InsertDocument
ON Acc.Document
FOR INSERT 
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE PartitionDocumentID IS NULL)
        BEGIN

            UPDATE  Acc.Document
            SET     PartitionDocumentID = COALESCE(NextDocumentID, 0) + RowNumber
            FROM    Acc.Document d
                    INNER JOIN 
                    (   SELECT  DocumentID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID ORDER BY DocumentID) [RowNumber]
                        FROM    inserted 
                        WHERE   PartitionDocumentID IS NULL
                    ) i
                        ON i.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (   SELECT  SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID, MAX(PartitionDocumentID)  [NextDocumentID]
                        FROM    Acc.Document
                        GROUP BY SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID
                    ) NextID
                        ON NextID.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID = d.SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID
        END
```